# Termination proof with functions using set comprehensions

Tags: isabelle, termination

Consider the following silly Isabelle definition of trees and subtrees:

```
datatype tree = Leaf int
              | Node tree tree

fun children :: "tree ⇒ tree set" where
"children (Leaf _) = {}" |
"children (Node a b) = {a, b}"

lemma children_decreasing_size:
  assumes "c ∈ children t"
  shows   "size c < size t"
using assms
by (induction t, auto)

function subtrees :: "tree ⇒ tree set" where
"subtrees t = { s | c s. c ∈ children t ∧ s ∈ subtrees c }"
by auto
termination
apply (relation "measure size", simp)
```

The termination proof of `subtrees` gets stuck at this point although the recursive calls are only ever made on children, which are strictly smaller by the well-founded `size` relation (as the trivial lemma shows).

The proof state is as follows:

```
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀t x xa xb. (xa, t) ∈ measure size
```

This is impossible to prove, of course, since the information that `xa` is a child of `t` is lost. Did I do something wrong? Is there anything I can do to save the proof? I note that I can formulate the same definition using lists instead of sets:

```
fun children_list :: "tree ⇒ tree list" where
"children_list (Leaf _) = []" |
"children_list (Node a b) = [a, b]"

function subtrees_list :: "tree ⇒ tree list" where
"subtrees_list t = concat (map subtrees_list (children_list t))"
by auto
termination
apply (relation "measure size", simp)
```

and get a more informative, provable termination goal:

```
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀t x.
       x ∈ set (children_list t) ⟹
       (x, t) ∈ measure size
```

Is this some limitation in Isabelle that I should just work around by not using sets for this?

Comment: Are you aware that, according to your definition, `subtrees` always returns the empty set?

Comment: Heh, good catch. This was simplified (too much) from something more complex I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The restriction to `c : children t` in the set comprehension for `subtrees` does not show up in the termination proof obligation, because the function package does not know anything a priori about `&`. Congruence rules can be used to achieve this. In this case, you can locally declare `conj_cong` as `[fundef_cong]` to essentially emulate a left-to-right evaluation order (although there is no such thing as evaluation in HOL). For example,

```
context notes conj_cong[fundef_cong] begin
fun subtrees :: ...
termination ...
end
```

The context block ensures that the declaration `conj_cong[fundef_cong]` is only in effect for this function definition.

The version with lists works because it uses the function `map` for which there is a congruence rule in place by default. The same should have worked for sets, if you had used the monadic bind operation on sets (rather than a set comprehension).

Comment: Another definition that works: `subtrees t = (⋃c∈children t. subtrees c)`. However, I would argue that a primitively-recursive definition is probably easier to work with.

Comment: @Manuel Eberl: `Union` is the monadic bind for sets, so your suggestion is exactly what i was referring to in my last sentence.

Comment: Oh, right. of course. I didn't notice that. In any case, it may not be obvious to all readers.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. After sleeping on it, I did also come up with the idea of using `(⋃c∈children t. subtrees c)`, although I wouldn't have guessed that this is what "monadic bind" meant in this context. So thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Actually, to be precise, `Union` is the monadic *join* for sets. But bind, can, of course be defined using `join` and `map`, where `map` is the set image operation.